# Remove Query params and ? from URL in firebase redirect

Tags: firebase, redirect, firebase-hosting

Does anybody know how to remove everything after the ? in a url within firebase?

I've tried just the redirect, then the rewrite on top of this.

```
"redirects": [
  { "type": 302, "source": "/testMenuBrowse.php?cat=36", "destination": "/" }
],
"rewrites": [
  { "type": 302, "source": "/testMenuBrowse{,/**}", "destination": "/" }
],
```

Whatever I do the end URL is `http://www.example.com/?cat=36`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not currently possible to strip query parameters when redirecting using Firebase Hosting. You might want to [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report/features/) for the functionality.